# How to create a table with long text and which packages use

Tags: tables, packages, longtable

Please, Help me inserting a table like this. I could not prepare this table easily because the long text i have to insert into the columns. I have been trying from some examples of stackechange but have not been successful. Perhaps the amount of text that includes the table. I am facing difficulties with merging the rows and columns. I am in an urgent need. Please Help !

Should I use all those packages? 
What and how each package is used?

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
```

This is the example i wanna get
Thanks

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{``“Utilidad y Derivación de las Emociones Primarias (Riso, W., 2008)''}
\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabu}{|[2pt]} >{\centering}p{3cm} | [2pt] >{\centering}p{3cm}
\tabucline[2pt]{-}
&{Emociones primarias} & {Derivación de las emociones primarias}\\ \tabucline[2pt]{-}
\multirow{6}{*}{\parbox{3 cm}{\textbf{Dolor}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\parbox{3 cm}{textbf{Sufrimiento}}\\
& Avisa cuando un órgano físico está funcionando mal o está siendo agredido, para que sea reparado o defendido. & Indica que hay una estructura mental afectada o un apego irracional que debe ser trabajado.\\
&\textbf{Miedo} & \textbf{Miedo psicológico}\\
& Protege ante un peligro real.& Indica que se ha dejado de actuar. La parálisis es sostenida por ideas irracionales.

\tabucline[2pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in your question and show us what you have so far.

Comment: How each package is used is easily spotted in each package's documentation. How a general tabular works: compile `\begin{tabular}{rlc} a & b & c \\ dmnu & ertu & fghi \end{tabular}` and it should give you an idea.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: tabular]

Here is a way to use a simple `tabular` with the enhancements offered by `booktabs`. Trying to learn multiple packages to do similar things all at once before you understand the basics is, I think, a recipe for confusion and frustration.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering% This is an environment - we probably don't want the extra spacing of center in addition to that added by table etc.
    \caption{``Utilidad y Derivación de las Emociones Primarias (Riso, W., 2008)''}

    \small
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{.425\linewidth}}}% The target layout does not centre the text so we don't want \centering
      \toprule% nicer rules courtesy of booktabs - but then we need to drop the verticals 
      Emociones primarias &  Derivación de las emociones primarias \\\midrule% Note that there is no & before the first column - & only comes between columns so if you define n columns, you can have at most n-1 & symbols in any row
      \textbf{Dolor} & \textbf{Sufrimiento}\\% No need for 6 rows of space for each title!
      Avisa cuando un órgano físico está funcionando mal o está siendo agredido, para que sea reparado o defendido. & Indica que hay una estructura mental afectada o un apego irracional que debe ser trabajado.\\\midrule% the p{} setting automatically lets these be multi-line - we don't want multiple rows on top of that and this is simpler as TeX does the hard work for us
      \textbf{Miedo} & \textbf{Miedo psicológico}\\
      Protege ante un peligro real.& Indica que se ha dejado de actuar. La parálisis es sostenida por ideas irracionales.\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you know how I could set different lengths for each column? I imagine that it's related to `{p{.425\linewidth},` but I haven't been able to sort this out. Thank you!

Comment: My bad, it was using `p{.425\linewidth}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|`. As explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286950/how-to-create-a-table-with-fixed-column-widths