# How to create a table with fixed column widths

Tags: tables

I've put in the following code:

```
\begin{tabular} {l{4cm} l{5cm}}
hello & foo\\
hello & bar\\
\end{tabular}
```

and it gives me an error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.199 \begin{tabular} {l{4cm} l{5cm}}
> ```

Why doesn't it work?  I'm trying to make a table with left justified text with fixed cell widths.  If I just specify `{l` l} it works, but with the widths it gives me that error.

Comment: Use `p{4cm}p{5cm}` not `l{4cm}`... It will be left aligned still then, but text will wrap around too. Please note that the width of the table is slightly larger than 9cm then

Comment: Have you seen any documentation that suggests `l{4cm}` should work? If you provide a link to it we could try to get it fixed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Tables says m{5em}.  It doesn't say what m does but I wanted my text left aligned.  Anyway, it didn't work even with m instead of l.

Comment: `m` is vertical mid alignment and requires the `array` package.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The standard column types are `l`, `c`, `r` and `p` which stands for `left aligned`, `centered` or `right alignment` and `parbox`.

Only the `p` - type can have a width argument, i.e. `p{somewidth}`, where `width` can be specified with any dimension `TeX`/`LaTeX` knows of.

The `p` - type is effectively `\parbox` which allows wrapping of text and content, which isn't possible (directly) in a `l` etc. type, for example an `itemize` or `enumerate` list.

The `array` package provides for example for the `m` type which is meant for vertical ('middle') aligned. In addition to this, `array` has the `\newcolumntype` macro which allows to define other column types, however, based on the existing 'base' types, i.e. `r`, `l`, `c` or `p`.

The `tabularx` package provides for the `X` columntype and the `siunitx` enables to use the `S` columntype.

Here's a small sample code for showing the width effects:

`\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{6cm}|}` will provide a tabular, that has the width of `4cm + 5cm + 4\tabcolsep + 3\arrayrulewidth`, since each column has a left and right `\tabcolsep` space, the later defaulting to `6pt`; and there are three `|`, so `3\arrayrulewidth` lengths are added.

In total, even `p{4cm}p{5cm}` will be wider than the expected `9cm`.

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
foo & bar
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|@{}p{4cm}@{}|@{}p{5cm}@{}|}
\hline
foo & bar
\end{tabular}


{%
 \renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}%
 \begin{tabular}{@{}p{4cm}@{}@{}p{5cm}@{}}
   foo & bar
 \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the last paragraph, it should be `4cm + 6cm` given `{|p{4cm}|p{6cm}|}`

Comment: How to put bottom line of the table (\hline), an error is coming in beamer environment
(error msg: Misplaced \noalign. ^^I^^I\hline)

Answer (score 34):

This workaround in the preamble solves the problem. You can simply use `C{width}` for centered entries. Replace C with L or R if raggedright or raggedleft is favoured.

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}p{#1}}
```