# Alignment of columns in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

Is there a command to make all columns of the same width? In my example the first two columns are small and the third is much wider.
I know that I could have set exact psarameters, but I'm just surprised the columns are not aligned automatically. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Suppose there's a wide line of text here}  \\
    \hline 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ %The third line is wider than the rest
    \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, take a look at this answer :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449117/90297

Comment: Related: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), but then you need to set the total width of the tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{|X|X|X|} 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Suppose there's a wide line of text here}  \\
        \hline 
        1 & 2 & 3 \\ %The third line is wider than the rest
        \hline 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX SX! That is because the standard `r,l,c` specifiers are for one-line content, and your first row natural length is much wider than the sum of the natural lengths of the columns in the second row. You can either use one of the`p, m`  or `X` column types, or load `makecell` and use the eponymous command for the 1st row: it allows for line breaks in standard cells.

Here is an (exaggerated) example of this last solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\makecell{Suppose\\ there's a\\ wide line\\ of text \\here}} \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ %The third line is wider than the rest
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]