# How to prevent table going beyond the page width

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table with 10 column but it goes beyond the width of the page and two columns are not seen. What should i do.

Comment: you may use table landscape or you can create table with fixed table width https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286950/how-to-create-a-table-with-fixed-column-widths

Comment: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)  might give you an idea of what you can do do make your table fit into the textwidth. If this does not help you, please provide a specific [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Please tell us *a lot more* about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ, what's the main document font size, and how tall and wide is the text block? Please also tell us more about the table, beyond the fact that it is supposed to contain 10 columns. Without these additional pieces of information, it's simply not possible to provide actionable advice.