# Convert 1 column to 2 column item

Tags: tex-core

How can I make number 1 single column like number 2 double column? 1 and 2 both of numbers are in the attached image.
I have tried to find this solution but did not get any solution.
[image]

Comment: Would a table with fixed column widths be sufficient? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286950/how-to-create-a-table-with-fixed-column-widths.

Comment: You can use both muilticol and paracol in the middle of a list, although both columns inherit \@totalleftmargin.  You will need to end them in the correct order.

Comment: thank you @Marijn

Comment: Thank you @JohnKormylo